# Сохраненный Python'ом CSV-файл неправильно отображается в Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

При сохранении CSV-файла и последующем его открытии Excel почему-то записывает все в один столбец.
Код для сохранения:

```py
with open(f'{name}.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as file:
table_writer = writer(file)
table_writer.writerows(schedule_table)
```

Что из себя представялет `schedule_table`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получаю такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К тому же, когда присылаю другу по Telegram, то еще и кодировка почему-то слетает, хотя я ее указал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, дело в разделителях - для *.csv по умолчанию это `,`, а Excel, согласно российским региональным настройкам ОС, делит по `;`. Попробуйте создать свой диалект через `csv.register_dialect()`.
Что касается кодировки, используйте `encoding='utf-8-sig'`, это добавит [специальный маркер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) - в данном случае `EF BB BF` - в начало *.csv файла, чтобы Excel правильно распознал символы.

```
import csv

schedule_table = [[chr(i+ord('А')) for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
csv.register_dialect('semicolon', delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
with open(rf'c:\test\out.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
    table_writer = csv.writer(file, dialect='semicolon')
    table_writer.writerows(schedule_table)
```

out.csv:

```
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
А;Б;В;Г;Д;Е;Ж;З;И;Й
```

[Подробная документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)